# Configure views folder for a bundle in Symfony 5

Tags: symfony

Here is  my controller:

```
<?php
//Controller/MenuController

namespace Mybdl\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class MenuController extends AbstractController {

    function menu(Request $request) 
    {
        return $this->render('MybdlBundle:menu:index.html.twig');
        //return $this->render('menu/index.html.twig');
    }

}
```

The view menu/index.html.twig is not found.
Here is my view with the full path at the top of the file

```
{#Resources/views/menu/index.html.twig#}
<div> Testing the menu </div>
{# {{ knp_menu_render('App\MenuBundle\Menu::class:mainMenu') }} #}
```

Here is the bundle extension:

```
<?php
//DependencyInjection/MybdlExtension.php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Mybdl\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Extension\Extension;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\YamlFileLoader;

class MybdlExtension extends Extension
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $loader = new YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.yml');
    }
}
```

Full code can be found here: https://github.com/karimmtl/Mysymfony5/tree/master/mine/mybdl-bundle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That syntax was [dropped](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/11051) after introducing a [new one](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/issues/3849). Every bundle installed will have a `@BundleName` namespace registered automatically.

So you should `render('@Mybdl/menu/index.html.twig');`.

Note that views have a [special, shortened syntax](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/best_practices.html#resources) that appends `Bundle` automatically.

Comment: thanks for the links too. It gonna be helpful for other people.